# Yii two MANY_MANY relations with limit

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to get rows of my model with a condition over two relations.
So, I have a model $model and two Relations:

$model has a MANY_MANY relation to $relation1 and
$relation1 has a MANY_MANY relation to $relations2.

I am trying to get $model where $relations2 is '1'.

So I tried:

```
$model->with('relation1.relations2'=>array('alias'=>'v'))->findAll('v.id=1');
```

This works.

But when I try to add a limit and offset to the findAll:

```
$model->with('relation1.relations2'=>array('alias'=>'v'))->findAll('condition'=>'v.id=1', 'offset'=>0, 'limit'=>10);
```

It says that it can't find the v alias (because he is trying to solve that with two queries, otherwise the limit cant be applied because of the MANY_MANY relationship).

So, actually I see the problem... But how can I solve it?

Comment: Do you have in log SQL string? Please, show it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$model->with('relation1'=>array('with'=>'relations2','alias'=>'v'))->findAll(array('condition'=>'v.id=1', 'offset'=>0, 'limit'=>10));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the [`together` property of CDbCriteria](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#together-detail)

```
$model->with(array('relation1.relations2'=>array('alias'=>'v')))->findAll('condition'=>'v.id=1', 'offset'=>0, 'limit'=>10,
'together'=>true);
```

You have already mentioned the reason, which is two queries being formed whereas you need one for limit, which can be accomplished by `together`.